# modal UIViewController inside a UITabBarController & UINavigationController

Tags: ios5, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to understand relationships between container controllers and their children. I've found Apple's distinction between the presentingViewController and the parentViewController somewhat arbitrary. For example, I created a storyboard with a UITabBarController containing a UINavigationController. The nav controller pushes in another UIViewController which in turn displays a modal view controller.

The storyboard image can be found at http://www.personal-lexicon.com/xyz/ViewControllerParentTest.png

By pushing the *Show Parent Info* button on each controller, I used the following code to printout its relationships.

```
- (IBAction)showParent:(id)sender {
const char *selfCls = class_getName(self.class);
NSLog(@"%@ = %p (%s)", self.title, self, selfCls);

const char *parentCls = class_getName(self.parentViewController.class);
NSLog(@"Parent Controller = %p (%s)", self.parentViewController, parentCls);

const char *presentingCls = class_getName(self.presentingViewController.class);
NSLog(@"Presenting Controller = %p (%s)", self.presentingViewController, presentingCls);

const char *navCls = class_getName(self.navigationController.class);
NSLog(@"Navigation Controller = %p (%s)", self.navigationController, navCls);

const char *tabCls = class_getName(self.tabBarController.class);
NSLog(@"TabBar Controller = %p (%s)\n\n", self.tabBarController, tabCls);
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
Root = 0x68ca810 (PTMasterViewController)
Parent Controller = 0x68ca610 (UINavigationController)
Presenting Controller = 0x0 (nil)
Navigation Controller = 0x68ca610 (UINavigationController)
TabBar Controller = 0x68ca3a0 (UITabBarController)

1st Push = 0x68d6f10 (PTMasterViewController)
Parent Controller = 0x68ca610 (UINavigationController)
Presenting Controller = 0x0 (nil)
Navigation Controller = 0x68ca610 (UINavigationController)
TabBar Controller = 0x68ca3a0 (UITabBarController)

Modal 1 = 0x68d7860 (PTMasterViewController)
Parent Controller = 0x0 (nil)
Presenting Controller = 0x68ca3a0 (UITabBarController)
Navigation Controller = 0x0 (nil)
TabBar Controller = 0x0 (nil)
```

The relationships for the *Root* and the *1st Push* controller make sense, but why does the modal controller show the UITabBarController as its presenting controller? To me, this should be the *1st Push* controller. Even the nav controller makes more sense than the tab bar controller.